# A basic mathematical question about: the derivation of the energy after particle decay shown in Griffiths Electrodynamics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

So I don't understand how they come to an expression for $E_\mu$ in the final step.

[image: picture griffiths derivation]

Comment: They probably solved a quadratic equation.

$$E_\mu + \sqrt{E_\mu^2-m_\mu^2c^4}=m_\pi c^2\quad\implies\quad E_\mu^2-m_\mu^2c^4=(m_\pi c^2-E_\mu)^2.$$

Comment: got it! thank you so much!!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  In the future please identify the source materials *in the body of your Question* that you are asking about.  Note that mathematical expressions can be included in posts using `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$ with [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).